# how to call a function which is inside require

Tags: javascript, function, requirejs

I am trying to understand how to use requirejs and I am already stuck to a very simple task.
How to I call a function defined inside require function and if this is the correct way of doing it.

example

```
require(['something'], function(something)
{

  function hello_world()
  {
    alert('hello world');
  }

});
```

Now how do I call the function hello_world from another file or from inside my html document. Obviously calling hello_world() returns undefined error.

I've start reading about the define method but if I understand correct, for every function I want to have, it must be in an external file?

Thank you.

EDIT
Also I tried this one

```
define('hello_world', function(){
  var hello_world = function()
  {
    alert('hello world');
  };

  return
  {
    hello_world: hello_world;
  }
});
```

EDIT 2 - A maybe more practical example

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script data-main="../scripts/test" src="../lib/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <svg width="400" height="100">
    <circle cx="24" cy="24" r="24"></circle>
    <circle cx="104" cy="64" r="24"></circle>
    <circle cx="184" cy="24" r="24"></circle>
  </svg>
  <br/>

  <a href='#' onclick="change_attributes">Change Attributes</a>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: false,
    paths: {
        d3: [
            '//d3js.org/d3.v3.min',
            '../lib/d3.min'
        ]
    }
});

require(['d3'], function (d3)
{
  // Selecting items
  var circles = d3.selectAll('circle');

  /*function change_attributes()
  {
    circles.style('fill', '#CF0000').attr('cy', 48);
  }*/

  function print_info(info)
  {
    info_screen.innerHTML = info;
  }

});


define('change_attributes', ['d3'], function(d3) {
    return function change_attributes() {
        circles.style('fill', '#CF0000').attr('cy', 48);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be in an external file, it just must have a name.

Comment: That `define` looks good. How did you use the module?

Comment: Well it is not really how I use the module, because is more of a question of how to call a function. For example how can I call the function from an anchor onlick event inside an html file.

Comment: Don't use inline event attributes. Attaching a handler with `$('someanchor').on('click', hello_world)` (or similar, without jQuery) will work wherever the function is in scope.

Comment: Hmm bad example. In any case, let's say that somehow I want to call this function from inline event. Can I do it?

Comment: Well, you could by explicitly exporting it to the global scope (`window.hello_world = …`). But you *shouldn't*, it breaks modularity.

Comment: So to sum it up, the only way to call a function no matter how simple it is, is by using an external file and defining it there. Right?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with external files. However, AMD modules are built on local scopes, and you need to make the function available as a handler you will need to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. In fact, modules and the whole idea of encapsulation is designed so you can't do things like that.

If you need to call hello_world from another module, you should define it as a module:

```
define('hello world', ['something'], function(something) {
    return function hello_world() {
        alert('hello world')
    }
})
```

And then specify it as a dependency:

```
require(['hello world'], function(hello_world) {
    hello_world()
})
```

Comment: Please don't use named `define` calls for advice to people beginning with RequireJS. It amounts to giving them bad habits that they'll later have to [undo](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulename).

Comment: @Louis: OP didn't seem to want an external file anyway, so it should be fine.

Comment: @Louis, AMD is supposed to be used with named defines, and it's one of the major advantages of it over CommonJS. With it you can simply concatenate all your files. Without it you need to use that big ugly optimizer. I'd rather choose first one.

Comment: I tried with your example, but I still get undefined. I don't know if I have the modular concept wrong....